# Why can't I query available in-app purchases

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, expo

I have a React Native Expo project. [I'm using this library.](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-in-app-purchases) - for in app payments on iOS.

The issue is, my query for available in-app purchases is returning nothing.

While the purchases can't be retrieved, I can't build any payments.

Notes:

- I'm testing RN app through the Expo iOS client
- In app purchases are `ready to submit` in Apple connect
- App has all data complete in Apple connect, but is not submitted yet

Here is the code. It's copypaste from the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/master/packages/expo-in-app-purchases)

```
 try {
        await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
        const items = Platform.select({
          ios: ["basic", "medium", "best"],
          android: [],

        });
        // Retrieve product details
        const getPurchasable = await InAppPurchases.getProductsAsync(items);
        const { responseCode, results } = getPurchasable;
```

Comment: @matt Do you have a source for this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? Currently facing the same thing .`getProductsAsync()` does not resolve and no `console.log`s show after it and I can't figure out why

Comment: @Scott check out my most recent answer on this thread, hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an unaccepted Paid applications agreement, you will not be able to receive purchases. Also, you can try to use iTunes Sandbox account

Comment: Thanks! I can confirm sandbox account is setup and app agreement is signed

Answer (score 1):

**tldr; `getProductsAsync` does not resolve on an ios simulator**

Old question, but I ran into the same issue, so it's worth answering:

1. `expo-in-app-purchases` only works in the bare workflow, so make sure you're using that
2. Whilst the expo [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases/) states that "*...in-app purchases require physical devices to work on both platforms and therefore cannot be tested on simulators."* in reality it's more complicated than this as some methods work just fine on simulators / emulators.

On Android most, if not all, methods work in the emulator. You can fetch products with `getProductsAsync`, but attempting to purchase them with `purchaseItemAsync` returns an error (unless you are signed in to a Google account on the emulator)

On iOS fewer methods work in the simulator. While `connectAsync` works, `getProducts` never resolves in a simulator.

Therefore, in order for `getProducts` to resolve, you need to test on a physical device. Either using a Sandbox account, or with TestFlight.